# Converting limited range YUV to sRGB using ImageMagick

Tags: image-processing, ffmpeg, imagemagick, rgb, yuv

I am trying to convert a set of raw video frames from *YUV444* to *sRGB* using **ImageMagick**.

Input format: Raw *YUV444* *limited range*, *BT.709* in planar data order.
Required output format: *sRGB* (set of *PNG* images).

Main issue: **ImageMagick** conversion always applies [JPEG conversion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr#JPEG_conversion).

- Remark about "*limited range*" YUV format:
  In 8 bits limited range YUV format, the range of Y is [16, 235] and the range of U, V is [16, 240]. (limited range BT.709 is used in HTDV systems).
  JPEG uses "*full range*" YUV format, where Y,U,V range is [0, 255].
  sRGB is used in PC systems, and the range of R,G,B is full range [0, 255].
  YUV and YCbCr are interchangeable.

For testing, I used the following sample image:

- Sample image in *sRGB* format (`rgb_input.png`):
  [image: rgb_input.png]

I converted the sample to *YUV444* format using **FFmpeg**:
`ffmpeg -y -colorspace bt709 -i rgb_input.png -pix_fmt yuv444p yuv_input.yuv`

Following image illustrates the YUV444 output (in planar data order):

- Input image for ImageMagick in *YUV444* format (`yuv_input.yuv` planar data order illustration):
  [image: yuv_input.yuv]

I converted `yuv_input.yuv` to *PNG* using **ImageMagick** converter (version 7.0.8-51):
`magick -depth 8 -interlace plane -size 128x96 -colorspace Rec709YCbCr -sampling-factor 4:4:4 yuv:yuv_input.yuv rgb_output_magick.png`

- Result of **ImageMagick** (`rgb_output_magick.png`):
  [image: rgb_output_magick]
  If you look carefully you see that the image is different than `rgb_input.png`.

Same conversion using `FFmpeg` (used as reference):
`ffmpeg -y -s 128x96 -colorspace bt709 -pix_fmt yuv444p -i yuv_input.yuv -pix_fmt rgb24 rgb_output_ffmpeg.png`

- Result of **FFmpeg** (`rgb_output_ffmpeg.png`):
  [image: rgb_output_ffmpeg.png]
  Note: The true format of my raw input video frames prevents me from using FFmpeg.

Conversion formula from 8 bits limited range YUV BT.709 to sRGB:
`R = 1.1644*Y + 0.00000*U + 1.79270*V - 248.10`
`G = 1.1644*Y - 0.21325*U - 0.53291*V + 76.878`
`B = 1.1644*Y + 2.11240*U + 0.00000*V - 289.02`

How can I do the above conversion using **ImageMagick** converter?

Comment: Perhaps use -color-matrix in place of -colorspace Rec709YCbCr. See https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#color-matrix. Then you can use your conversion coefficients. You do not need to fill in all the extra rows and columns. Just use your coefficients as a 3x3 matrix. P.S. why are you using -colorspace Rec709YCbCr. Should you not just use -colorspace YUV, which I think should come after your read in your raw image, not before? See https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#colorspace

Comment: The `color-matrix` syntax has a crazy syntax. I think I do need to use 6x6 matrix because of the 3 offsets. Placing the `-colorspace Rec709YCbCr` after gives a very small difference (2 gray levels), and `-colorspace YUV` is different by 1 gray level from `-colorspace Rec709YCbCr`. Still looks like JPEG conversion formula.

Comment: Can you (or anyone) please post an answer using `-color-matrix`? I think I can figure out how to use it, but I prefer accepting an answer.

Comment: I tried to duplicate your commands. The ffmpeg command seemed to work, but your ImageMagick command failed with the error `magick: unexpected end-of-file 'yuv_input.yuv': No such file or directory`. So I am not sure if this is a problem with IM or ffmpeg. I am using IM 7.0.8.51 on Mac OSX Sierra. Why are you using bt709 and not yuv444 in your ffmpeg command and -colorspace YUV in your IM command? Perhaps see https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/colorspace. Note I am not an expert on ffmpeg or raw formats.

Comment: I am using Windows 10, but I don't think it's an OS problem. The version I downloaded is `ImageMagick-7.0.8-52-Q8-x64-static.exe`. About using bt709: `-sampling-factor 4:4:4 yuv:yuv_input.yuv` applies yuv444. I can only guess `Rec709YCbCr` flag is designed for converting RGB to YUV, but not from YUV to RGB.

Comment: Rec709YCbCr is for converting from RGB to YCbCr not YUV, as far as I know.

Comment: In ImageMagick, colorspaces rec709YCbCr, YCbCr and YUV all have different coefficients. See https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#colorspace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you requested, this would be the ImageMagick color-matrix command for your transform, **assuming it makes sense**. ImageMagick color-matrix values are normalized to the range 0 to 1, including the offset (right-most) term. I assume your offsets are in the range 0 to 255 (8-bit). So I am not sure if this even makes sense. Nevertheless, here is the way it would look.

```
magick input -color-matrix \
"1.1644 0.00000 1.79270 0, 0, -0.9729 \
1.1644 -0.21325 -0.53291 0, 0, 0.30148 \
1.1644 2.11240 0.00000 0, 0, -1.1334 \
0 0 0 1, 0, 0 \
0 0 0 0, 1, 0 \
0 0 0 0, 0, 1" output
```

See http://www.adobetutorialz.com/articles/1987/1/Color-Matrix

Comment: You forgot few minus signs... Can you please post the complete command? Using `-color-matrix`, I am getting two output images with weird colors (`rgb_output_magick-0.png` and `rgb_output_magick-1.png`). Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I copied your 3 lines and then tried to remove the excess to get the matrix terms only and accidentally removed the minus signs. I have fixed it above, but still do not know if that is even relevant to what you want to do or correct. There should be no reason for getting two output images -0 and -1, unless you have copied it wrong. It works fine for me with one input. Try with no other commands included other than some PNG or JPG input and PNG or JPG output. Does that give multiple output results? If so, post your full command. **In Window syntax, change the end of line \ to ^**

Comment: I figure out the problem. instead of `yuv:yuv_input.yuv`, I had to use: `rgb:yuv_input.yuv` (`-color-matrix` works with RGB input and gives weird results with YUV input).

Comment: Complete command is: `magick -interlace plane -size 128x96 rgb:yuv_input.yuv -color-matrix "1.1644 0.0 1.79270 0.0, 0.0, -0.97294 1.1644 -0.21325 -0.53291 0.0, 0.0, 0.30148 1.1644 2.11240 0.0 0.0, 0.0, -1.13340 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0, 0.0, 1.0" rgb_output_magick.png`

Comment: Your command only works for me if I specify -depth 8 as `im7 magick -interlace plane -depth 8 -size 128x96 rgb:yuv_input.yuv -color-matrix "1.1644 0.0 1.79270 0.0, 0.0, -0.97294 1.1644 -0.21325 -0.53291 0.0, 0.0, 0.30148 1.1644 2.11240 0.0 0.0, 0.0, -1.13340 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0, 0.0, 1.0" rgb_output_magick.png`. It results in one output, which seems to match your rgb_input.png. -depth 8 is needed on a Q16 compile of ImageMagick; otherwise, IM assumes it is depth 16 and the command fails. I suggest you post this command back to your first post.